# Python concatenate SET or LIST

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I try to test two to get set from list:

In first from each list create set and then union to result set
or create one list and the return the set of list.

My result looks like no matter in which way to use, is it so? Or I have error logic in my research, or may be exist best way for such union?

```
import time


def set_from_set(*args):
    l = set()
    return set().union(*args)


def set_from_list(*args):
    l = []
    for larg in args:
        l += larg
    return set(l)


l1 = [x for x in range(1000000)]
l2 = [x for x in range(1000000)]
l3 = [x for x in range(1000000)]
dl1, dl2 = 0, 0

for x in range(100):
    start = time.time()
    set_from_list(l1, l2, l3)
    dl1 += time.time() - start


for x in range(100):
    start = time.time()
    set_from_set(l1, l2, l3)
    dl2 += time.time() - start


print(dl1, dl2)
```

result:

> 19.815733194351196 16.40732741355896

Comment: Your `set_from_set` isn't actually building the union you want; it just constructs a bunch of intermediate sets and throws them away, then returns the empty set you constructed on the first line.

Comment: Why not just `set().union(l1, l2, l3)`?

Comment: @user2357112 in real i don know how much list i will have

Comment: @vaultah yep, just noticed :)

Comment: @BearBrown then use `set().union(*args)`

Comment: thank all, i fixed the error, but timing still looks almost equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in this function

```
def set_from_set(*args):
     l= set()
     for larg in args:
         l.union(set(larg))
     return l
```

the `.union()` function [returns a new set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects), it doesn't modify your old set in place.

Comment: thank you it fix me code logic error but , time results still almost equal

Comment: You're testing which method is faster, right? It seems to me like a 20% difference is actually pretty significant in comparing two methods.